# How Set having Map.entrySet() values

Tags: java

I am a confused by the map interface. It has to use the `entrySet()` method for a collection view (or to use an iterator). An `entrySet()` returns a Set that contains the elements of its Map. Again, each of these Set elements is a `Map.Entry` object. How is that possible? As Set contains only one field, whereas `Map.Entry` is a key value pair? Can you explain briefly with example & flow .

Comment: This `Set` contains the key-value pairs of the map. A `Map.Entry` has the key as much as the value.

Answer (score 2):

A `Set` contains elements of some reference type. `Map.Entry` is a reference type, and can be used as the element of a `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you have a data structure with key and value. One key for one value, one value for one key.

`Map<K,V>` is an interface for this data structure. It allows to get value by key.

`Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>` is an interface for the same data structure. It allows to get all pairs of key-value.

Answer (score 0):

As per Orcale documentation : entrySet() of Map returns a Set view of the mappings contained in map. The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa. The Map.entrySet method returns a collection-view of the map, whose elements are of this class. The only way to obtain a reference to a map entry is from the iterator of this collection-view. These Map.Entry objects are valid only for the duration of the iteration; more formally, the behavior of a map entry is undefined if the backing map has been modified after the entry was returned by the iterator.
Follow the below code snippet for further explanation :-

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

public class MapEntry {
    public static void main(String... q){
        Map<String,Integer> mapObj = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

        mapObj.put("1", new Integer(1));
        mapObj.put("2", new Integer(2));
        mapObj.put("3", new Integer(3));
        mapObj.put("4", new Integer(4));

       // First Approach  
       Set outMap = mapObj.entrySet();
       for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> tempMap : mapObj.entrySet()){
           System.out.println("KEY : "+tempMap.getKey());
           System.out.println("VALUE : "+tempMap.getValue());
       }

       // Second Approach
       for(Iterator it = mapObj.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();){
           Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)it.next();
           System.out.println("2nd Approach - Key : "+me.getKey());
           System.out.println("2nd Approach - Value : "+me.getValue());
       }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.